# remember & display operation total on refresh

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I'm trying to fetch all `localStorage` stored data from last visit entered input values. 
So far, I'm able to store & display `input`'s 1 & 2 but not the subtraction result between these 2.

**I would like to store and display on page load/refresh the last visit subtraction result as well.**

Example, you go to the fiddle the first time, you see no values:
[image]

You type in values and you see the subtraction result below:
[image]

Finally you reload the fiddle and see only the last entered `input` values but not the subtraction result (which would be desired as well):

[image]

**[|=========> External JSFiddle (not working if I embed it) <=========|](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/a7bs8jh1/2/)**

**HTML:**

```
<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="input1" value="0" name="input1">
    <input type="text" id="input2" value="0" name="input2">
</form>
<span id="total"></span>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getLocalStorage();
});
$("form").keyup(function() {
    var input1 = parseFloat($("#input1").val());
    var input2 = parseFloat($("#input2").val());
    var total = input2 - input1;
    $("#total").text(total);
});
function getLocalStorage() {
    if (localStorage["input1"]) {
        $('#input1').val(localStorage["input1"]);
    }
    if (localStorage["input2"]) {
        $('#input2').val(localStorage["input2"]);
    }
    if (localStorage[$("#total")]) {
        $('#total').html(localStorage[$("#total")]);
    }
};
$('input').keyup(function() {
    localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    localStorage[$("#total")] = $(this).html();
});
```

Couple SO questions I checked with no luck:

- [Loading total on form load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864164/loading-total-on-form-load)
- [Can't get localStorage to display output on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274991/cant-get-localstorage-to-display-output-on-refresh)

Comment: There's little to no reason to store the total in localstorage, you could just calculate that part.

Comment: As the above posters say, you don't need to store it. (In fact, you shouldn't.) The immediate problem, however, is that `localStorage` needs strings as the property name not jQuery objects.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a7bs8jh1/3/

Comment: @Syden thanks! I really appreciate it.

Comment: oh, wait, i thought this was the question where i posted a completely useless sarcastic comment, carry on. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store and retrieve `localStorage` as a string, not the jquery object for `$('#total')`. I updated your code to set `localStorage['total']` instead of `localStorage[$('#total')]`. I also consolidated the `$("form").keyup()` and `$("input").keyup()` event handlers because it looks like you only need `$("input").keyup()`.

https://jsfiddle.net/a7bs8jh1/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    getLocalStorage();
});
function getLocalStorage() {
    if (localStorage["input1"]) {
        $('#input1').val(localStorage["input1"]);
    }
    if (localStorage["input2"]) {
        $('#input2').val(localStorage["input2"]);
    }
    if (localStorage['total']) {
        $('#total').html(localStorage['total']);
    }
};
$('input').keyup(function() {
    var input1 = parseFloat($("#input1").val());
    var input2 = parseFloat($("#input2").val());
    var total = input2 - input1;
    localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    localStorage['total'] = total;
    $("#total").text(total);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="input1" value="0" name="input1">
    <input type="text" id="input2" value="0" name="input2">
</form>
<span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information. Also, just as we expect questions to include code in the question itself, answers should have the code in the answer itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the total wrong. Check this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7bs8jh1/4/).

Here is the modified code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getLocalStorage();
});
$("form").keyup(function() {
    var input1 = parseFloat($("#input1").val());
    var input2 = parseFloat($("#input2").val());
    var total = input2 - input1;
    $("#total").text(total);
});
function getLocalStorage() {
    if (localStorage["input1"]) {
        $('#input1').val(localStorage["input1"]);
    }
    if (localStorage["input2"]) {
        $('#input2').val(localStorage["input2"]);
    }
    if (localStorage["total"]) {            
        $('#total').html(localStorage["total"]);
    }
};

$('input').keyup(function() {
    localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    localStorage["total"] = $('#total').html();
});
```

Comment: @Syden How is it that my answer was not the right one?

Comment: Oh, sorry I did not see that.

Comment: It's ok, here's +10 though for your time ;)